# Prove: If $\mathit R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $\mathit I=(x)\subseteq R[x]$, then $R[x] / (x)\cong R$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

I know that to show a ring is isomorphic to another ring, I have to find a bijective ring homomorphism between the two rings. Or I could use the F.H.T. but I would also need a function to make that happen (If I'm thinking about it correctly). Do I need to just make up my own function and prove that it is a bijective ring homomorphism? If so, where do I start? Thanks!

Comment: Try to find a surjective map $p: R[x] \to R$ such that $\ker p = (x)$. Then you can use homomorphism theorem, which states that for any map $T : A\to B$ between commutative rings $A/\ker T \cong \operatorname{Im} T$.

Comment: Where to start: look for your question first.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f: R[x] \to R$ by $f(p(x))=p(0)$. Prove this is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $(x)$ and use first isomorphism theorem

Consequence: If in addtion $R[x]$ is a PID, then the ideal $(x)$ is maximal and so $R$ is a field